Add key and value inside key returns in JSON & Python
I have a JSON file with this format and I'm trying to insert a key and value, as a value to a key.
{
    "A": {
        "A": "2024-07-17 20:06:35.185784",
        "B": "2024-07-17 20:27:15.531860"
    },
    "B": {
        "A": "2024-07-17 20:27:15.531860",
        "B": "2024-07-17 20:27:15.531860"
        #I want to insert here "C" : "Some text"
    }
}

Here is my code :
with open('/Users/admin/Downloads/files/date.json') as jsonfile:
    data = json.load(jsonfile)

data['B']['C'] = "Some text"        

with open('/Users/admin/Downloads/files/date.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    json.dump(data, jsonfile, indent=4)

The error feedback I get :
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 378, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/Downloads/files/sharedvc.py", line 78, in on_voice_state_update
    data[B][C] = "Some text"

KeyError: 'C'


The code in your error message is not the same as in the code snippet. There's no quotes in data[B][C].

Yeah I changed the original stuff by B and C and forgot the snippets

The problem is almost certainly that data[B] doesn't exist. It won't create intermediate dictionaries.

Take a look at the .setdefault() method to help with this.

Even after the edit there are still no quotes in the indexes in the error message. data[B][C] is not the same as data['B']['C']. What is the value of the B variable in the actual code?
